# Get all strings matching wanted length by repeating x characters from first string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have the following string:

```
string = '---A---B-C'
```

And I have the following dict:

```
min_max_values = {'A': [2,4], 'B': [2, 15], 'C': [1, 2]}
```

My goal is to generate new strings from the first string:

- All new strings must match a pre-defined length
- All groups of character must be separated by the same amount of '-' as the original string
- Only characters from the dict can be repeated, but there is a minimum and a maximum amount of time they can be repeated ([min, max]). For example, 'A' has to be used at least 2 times but at most 4 times.

Here is an exemple to make myself clear:

```
string = '---A---B-C'
min_max_values = {'A': [2,4], 'B': [2, 15], 'C': [1, 2]}

wanted_length = 20

Outputs :
'---AAAA---BBBBBBBB-C'
'---AAAA---BBBBBBB-CC'
'---AAA---BBBBBBBBB-C'
'---AAA---BBBBBBBB-CC'
'---AA---BBBBBBBBBB-C'
'---AA---BBBBBBBBB-CC'
```

I can see how I can do that with only one character, maybe two, but I have absolutely no idea of how I can deal with all the combinations ! Any ideas ?

## EDIT

@AChampion asked me to show code in comments and explain where I'm stuck.

So, here is my current code (with new_strings being my final output) *- it is fully working if you want to copy and paste it -*:

```
import re

string = '---A---B-C'
split_string = re.findall('-*', string)
characters = re.findall('[A-Z]', string)
min_max_values = {'A': [2,4], 'B': [2, 15], 'C': [1, 2]}
wanted_length = 20
combinations = get_combinations(string, min_max_values, wanted_length)
new_strings = []

for combination in combinations:
    new_string = ''
    character_index = 0
    for chunk in cut_string:
        print new_string
        if chunk:
            new_string += chunk
        elif character_index < len(characters):
            character = characters[character_index]
            new_string += character*combination[character]
            character_index += 1
    new_strings.append(new_string)


def get_combinations(string, min_max_values, wanted_length):
    constant_length = string.count('-') # 7
    remaining_length = wanted_length - constant_length # 13
    # What I want to do : find combinations that will add up to the remaining_length
    # i.e. : combinations = [{'A': 4, 'B': 8, 'C': 1}, {'A': 4, 'B': 7, 'C': 2}, {'A': 3, 'B': 9, 'C': 1}, {'A': 3, 'B': 8, 'C': 2}, {'A': 2, 'B': 10, 'C': 1}, {'A': 2, 'B': 9, 'C': 2}]
    combinations = [{'A': 4, 'B': 8, 'C': 1}, {'A': 4, 'B': 7, 'C': 2}, {'A': 3, 'B': 9, 'C': 1}, {'A': 3, 'B': 8, 'C': 2}, {'A': 2, 'B': 10, 'C': 1}, {'A': 2, 'B': 9, 'C': 2}]
    return combinations
```

And I'm stuck at "combinations". I don't know how to automatically generate this dict. I would like to add up the three values so that they match the remaining length but I don't know how to do that. My even bigger problem is that this method has to work with any number of characters in the original string (e.g. ---A----B---D---E--F---G). The only given is that the string only contains dashes and characters ; and that the characters will always be in the min_max_values dict.

I didn't put this code in the first place because even the rest of my code seems wrong. I'm open to any input / improvement.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and where you are getting stuck? (Note: you've duplicated line 2 in your output).

Comment: Yes, please see my edit. (I've also edited the duplicated output, thanks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product()` to generate the combinations of `'A'` and `'B'` and then subtract from your wanted string length to see if you can fit `'C'`. It's easier to operate on `range()`s so a quick dict comprehension can turn the `min_max_values` to a set of `ranges`:

```
import itertools as it

dashes = string.count('-')
ranges = {k: range(v[0], v[1]+1) for k, v in min_max_values.items()}
for a, b in it.product(ranges['A'], ranges['B']):
    c = wanted_length - dashes - a - b
    if c in ranges['C']:
        print('---{}---{}-{}'.format('A'*a, 'B'*b, 'C'*c))
```

Output:

```
---AA---BBBBBBBBB-CC
---AA---BBBBBBBBBB-C
---AAA---BBBBBBBB-CC
---AAA---BBBBBBBBB-C
---AAAA---BBBBBBB-CC
---AAAA---BBBBBBBB-C
```

To turn this into a list of dicts:

```
results = []
for a, b in it.product(ranges['A'], ranges['B']):
    c = wanted_length - dashes - a - b
    if c in ranges['C']:
        results.append({'A': a, 'B': b, 'C': c})
print(results)
```

Output:

```
[{'A': 2, 'B': 9, 'C': 2},
 {'A': 2, 'B': 10, 'C': 1},
 {'A': 3, 'B': 8, 'C': 2},
 {'A': 3, 'B': 9, 'C': 1},
 {'A': 4, 'B': 7, 'C': 2},
 {'A': 4, 'B': 8, 'C': 1}]
```

You could just `it.product(ranges['A'], ranges['B'], ranges['C'])` and get the same result but it is a little less efficient:

```
[{'A':a, 'B':b, 'C':c} for a, b, c in it.product(ranges['A'], ranges['B'], ranges['C']) if a+b+c=20-dashes]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about itertools which helps a lot. 
I would like to use `it.product(*ranges.values())` because there could be A, B, C in the dict, but there could also be only A and B or A,B,C,D, etc.
And I would only keep the products that sums up to the good length.
However, when using this, I can't make the dict. Do you know how I could do this with an unknown number of keys, and not just A,B,C ?
(If I use min_max_values.keys(), does it always follow the same order as the tuples from list(it.product(*ranges.values())) ?

Comment: You will need to use a `list` and not a `dict` for ranges, because order of dicts is not guaranteed, so doing `*ranges.values()` could have an unexpected order.